# No column was specified for column 1 of 'VIEW_NAME'

Tags: sql, view, alias

I'm trying to create a simple little view but I'm keep getting errors all over the query. `[Accepted by Month]` has the error `No column was specified for column 1 of 'Accepted by Month'`. I have looked up pretty much everything online and I know that I need to give the columns I select an alias but whenever I do that it just gives me an error under the `AS` I use for the column aliases saying `incorrect syntax near`. Plus I'm getting errors with the comma in the `SELECT` statement and an error for `FROM` both saying incorrect syntax.

Someone show me how I should write this query because I haven't made any progress in over an hour on a simple `CREATE VIEW`.

```
USE Database_Name
GO
CREATE VIEW [Accepted by Month] AS
SELECT Case.Accepted, Case.CaseID
FROM Case;
```

Comment: Probably because `case` is a reserved word.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the error messages you're getting.

Comment: There you go @Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to solve your problem:

```
USE Database_Name
GO
CREATE VIEW [Accepted by Month] AS
SELECT [Case].Accepted, [Case].CaseID
FROM [Case];
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are required if you use keywords or special chars in the column names or identifiers or names with white space.

```
USE Database_Name
GO
CREATE VIEW [Accepted by Month] (Accepted, CaseID) AS
SELECT Accepted, CaseID
FROM [Case];
```